# Generic selenium testing in Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: azure, selenium, automated-tests, azure-devops, pipeline

I am currently working on generic selenium tests to add to all my pipelines.

Because all my projects are similar (webshops) but have different solutions, I created a independent project to execute unit tests for all these webshops. I am wondering if it is possible to execute these tests in the independent project the Azure DevOps pipeline.

[image: Azure DevOps Pipeline example]
What are my possibilities?

Thank you,
Thomas

Comment: If you build the solution, you should be able to execute the tests. What is actually the problem?

Comment: @PanuOksala The problem is that the tests are in another solution. I am currently working on a custom DevOps Pipeline task to do the tests for me.

Comment: Sorry for adding a comment a year later, but I am looking for an answer to this too, did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: @GregP No I sadly never got to finish it. I recommend creating a powershell script that executes the generic selenium project with certain parameters to specify what project you're testing. After that, you could execute the script in the pipeline with the specific parameters!